# Can't import SSL key using keytool

Tags: jira, keytool, crucible, fisheye

I have a problem with keytool tool.

I have a FishEye/Crucible server which needed to be connected to my Jira server. My Jira server uses SSL. I'm trying to import ssl certificate using the following command:

```
 keytool -importcert -alias "JiraCert" -file jira.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
Enter keystore password:  
Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
Enter keystore password:  
Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
Enter keystore password:  
Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
Too many failures - try later
```

but it asks for password which is empty one as I managed to list available certificates in that keystore with no password, just Enter is pressed.

What do you think, what shall I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default password for the keystore in Java is 'changeit' - try using that.